# Drawing arcs very close to segments with pict2e package

Tags: picture-mode

I would like to recreate this drawing only using the [pict2e](https://ctan.org/pkg/pict2e?lang=en) package, I present my progress, but I have the following question, it does not look much like the drawing except in +1,-1, it seems to me that happens because I don't used a convenient command (`\qbezier`). Could help improving it or perhaps with another way more faithful to the image?

## My progress

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(12,12)
\thicklines

% Tracing the coordinate axes
\put(6,6){\vector(1,0){5}}              % Semiaxis X    (A)
\put(6,6){\vector(-1,0){5}}             % Semiaxis -X   (B)
\put(6,6){\vector(0,1){5}}              % Semiaxis Y    (C)
\put(6,6){\vector(0,-1){5}}             % Semiaxis -Y   (D)

% Marking the metrics
\put(7.7,7.7){\makebox(0,0){$C_1$}}
\put(8.5,8.5){\makebox(0,0){$C_2$}}
\put(9.5,9.5){\makebox(0,0){$C_3$}}
\put(10.3,10.3){\makebox(0,0){$C_\infty$}}

% Drawing $C_1$
\put(10,6){\line(-1,1){4}}              % (A-C)
\put(6,10){\line(-1,-1){4}}             % (C-B)
\put(2,6){\line(1,-1){4}}               % (B-D)
\put(6,2){\line(1,1){4}}                % (D-A)

% Marking the ``ones''
\put(10.1,5.75){\makebox(0,0){$1$}}     % (A)
\put(5.7,10.25){\makebox(0,0){$1$}}     % (C)
\put(1.7,5.75){\makebox(0,0){$-1$}}     % (B)
\put(5.7,1.75){\makebox(0,0){$-1$}}     % (D)

% Drawing $C_\infty$
\put(10,2){\line(0,1){8}}               % (A-C)
\put(10,10){\line(-1,0){8}}             % (C-B)
\put(2,10){\line(0,-1){8}}              % (B-D)
\put(2,2){\line(1,0){8}}                % (D-A)

% Marking the circles
\put(10,6){\circle*{0.15}}              % (A)
\put(6,10){\circle*{0.15}}              % (C)
\put(2,6){\circle*{0.15}}               % (B)
\put(6,2){\circle*{0.15}}               % (D)

% Drawing $C_2$ with bezier curves
\qbezier(2,6)(2.5,2.5)(6,2)
\qbezier(6,2)(9.5,2.5)(10,6)
\qbezier(10,6)(9.5,9.5)(6,10)
\qbezier(6,10)(2.5,9.5)(2,6)

% Drawing $C_3$ with bezier curves
\qbezier(2,6)(1.75,1.75)(6,2)
\qbezier(6,2)(10.25,1.75)(10,6)
\qbezier(10,6)(10.25,10.25)(6,10)
\qbezier(6,10)(1.75,10.25)(2,6)
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much.

## Question

In my progress, in values close to $\pm 1$, the curves $C_2$ and $C_3$ come out slightly from the larger square, but in the drawing below it does not leave the square.

## Drawing that I want to recreate

[image: Drawing with pict2e package]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, your suspicion is correct, and you can get rid of the line crossings by switching to cubic Bezier curves.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(12,12)
\thicklines

% Tracing the coordinate axes
\put(6,6){\vector(1,0){5}}              % Semiaxis X    (A)
\put(6,6){\vector(-1,0){5}}             % Semiaxis -X   (B)
\put(6,6){\vector(0,1){5}}              % Semiaxis Y    (C)
\put(6,6){\vector(0,-1){5}}             % Semiaxis -Y   (D)

% Marking the metrics
\put(7.7,7.7){\makebox(0,0){$C_1$}}
\put(8.5,8.5){\makebox(0,0){$C_2$}}
\put(9.5,9.5){\makebox(0,0){$C_3$}}
\put(10.3,10.3){\makebox(0,0){$C_\infty$}}

% Drawing $C_1$
\put(10,6){\line(-1,1){4}}              % (A-C)
\put(6,10){\line(-1,-1){4}}             % (C-B)
\put(2,6){\line(1,-1){4}}               % (B-D)
\put(6,2){\line(1,1){4}}                % (D-A)

% Marking the ``ones''
\put(10.1,5.75){\makebox(0,0){$1$}}     % (A)
\put(5.7,10.25){\makebox(0,0){$1$}}     % (C)
\put(1.7,5.75){\makebox(0,0){$-1$}}     % (B)
\put(5.7,1.75){\makebox(0,0){$-1$}}     % (D)

% Drawing $C_\infty$
\put(10,2){\line(0,1){8}}               % (A-C)
\put(10,10){\line(-1,0){8}}             % (C-B)
\put(2,10){\line(0,-1){8}}              % (B-D)
\put(2,2){\line(1,0){8}}                % (D-A)

% Drawing $C_2$ with bezier curves
\cbezier(2,6)(2,4)(4,2)(6,2)
\cbezier(6,2)(8,2)(10,4)(10,6)
\cbezier(10,6)(10,8)(8,10)(6,10)
\cbezier(6,10)(4,10)(2,8)(2,6)

% Drawing $C_3$ with bezier curves
\cbezier(2,6)(2,2.5)(2.5,2)(6,2)
\cbezier(6,2)(9.5,2)(10,2.5)(10,6)
\cbezier(10,6)(10,9.5)(9.5,10)(6,10)
\cbezier(6,10)(2.5,10)(2,9.5)(2,6)
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, I added the circles filled in the vertices and I am happy with the drawing obtained.